Question regarding multiple bank statements to submit for UK visa
I have applied for a UK tourist visa and I understand I need to submit 6 months of bank statements, which show my salary being credited to my account. I'll also be submitting 6 months of pay slips.
Now while my bank statements do show the salary being credited every month into my account (origin of funds) I also have another bank account where I keep transferring a fairly good amount of money from my salary account to that bank account from time to time. I usually pay my day-to-day bills and transactions from that account while I pay larger bills (like rent, etc) from my salary account. So the transactions to my secondary bank account are shown in the bank statements.
So my question is should I be submitting just my salary account bank statements or should I submit both my bank accounts statements for the last 6 months?
Also in my application I have put down my monthly expenditure as X and that is more or less from both the accounts combined.
PS: I have also made two large deposits from my salary account to my other account (around 2,500 + 2,500 pounds) for the purpose of the trip in the last 2 weeks so those will also show up in my latest transactions.

You need to provide both sets of statements so that UKVI can get the full picture. What makes you think that might not be necessary?

Hello. Thanks for your response. I was just wondering from the point of view that i didn't want to over submit documents to confuse the visa officer. So i thought it would be enough to just submit my salary account bank statement since that has my proof of income as well as proof of sufficient funds.

Would I also need to mention anything about it in a cover letter or is it okay if I just submit both my bank statements?


should I be submitting just my salary account bank statements or should I submit both my bank accounts statements for the last 6 months?

You need to provide both sets of statements so that UKVI can get the full picture. It’s not just about proof of funds. See Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me? The way you operate your two bank accounts is very common; ECOs will be used to seeing it and able to follow it.
In a comment you asked:

Would I also need to mention anything about it in a cover letter or is it okay if I just submit both my bank statements?

Either should be fine. If you’re worried the ECO might miss or misunderstand something in the statements, you can explain in the covering letter.
